# ImageView CenterCropping is not working with adapter Android

Tags: java, android, imageview

I have an adapter to show items. It contains an ImageView

```
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/iv_location"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:adjustViewBounds="true"
  android:background="@drawable/location_place_holder"
  android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

On ImageView `android:adjustViewBounds="true"  android:scaleType="centerCrop"`

And the image is loaded using Glide dynamically.

```
public static void loadImage(Context mContext, String uri, @DrawableRes int placeHolderId, ImageView view) {
    Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(uri)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .placeholder(placeHolderId)
            .into(view);
}
```

And the problem is the Image is skewed[image].

Answer (score 3):

You have to use functions provide by glide to do that.

```
 public static void loadImage(Context mContext, String uri, @DrawableRes int placeHolderId, ImageView view) {
    Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(uri)
            .centerCrop()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .placeholder(placeHolderId)
            .into(view);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this you can user `centerCrop()` of glide for this purpose

```
public static void loadImage(Context mContext, String uri, @DrawableRes int placeHolderId, ImageView view) {
Glide.with(mContext)
        .load(uri)
        .centerCrop()
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
        .placeholder(placeHolderId)
        .into(view);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all without resize parameter Center crop is not working.

Use Picasso library

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

if Uri is direct image download url.

```
public static void loadImage(Context mContext, String uri, @DrawableRes int placeHolderId, ImageView view) {
Picasso.with(this)
     .load(uri)           
     .resize(400, 400)
     .centerCrop()                                           
     .into(view);}
```

if uri is local path then use thie code for load Image

```
Picasso.with(this)
     .load(new File(uri))           
     .resize(400, 400)
     .centerCrop()                                           
     .into(view);
```